# Returning an object from a form using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, callback

I am looking for some advice regarding the design of the below scenario:

**High level info:**

- I have a WPF GUI that contains a grid listing some cars info.
- It contains a button, "Add new Car..." that pops-up a form with some base fields so that the user can add a new ICar object in the list.
- Both main window and form are designed following up the MVVM pattern (and some decoupling of the commands as well).

**Flow and question:**

- The button "Add new Car..." is bound to a main window command that loads up the form.
- The form is bound to a background object, so that when the user presses "Ok", I would want the object to be returned to the original window.

However I don't know how to design that last step, i.e. should I:

1. Have some public methods in my form to be called so that it is by itself:

   - Loading the form (ShowDialog..).
   - Does the properties bindings (already done)
   - Returns the new Car object to the caller (here the main window)?
2. Or:

   - Call the form.ShowDialog() from the main window.
   - Do something else (which I can't find how to) to get back the new Car object defined by the user?

Thank you!

Comment: If in doubt, don't use events in WPF. In fact as far as I can see none of the control flows seems to fit with the MVVM pattern. I prefer to consider everything from the Model side, and approach using a TDD methodology. First create your a model/model view that allows you to do all the work you want. In this case an AddCar method, which I assume takes an ICar object. Then from the view figure out how to make an ICar to call the `Model.AddCar(ICar)` method

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
interface IPresentationService
{
    bool ShowInDialog(ViewModel viewModel);
}

class CarViewModel : ViewModel {}
class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    [Import]
    private IPresentationService presentationService;

    private void AddNewCar()
    {
        var car = new CarViewModel();
        if (presentationService.ShowInDialog(car))
        {
            Cars.Add(car);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Cars = new ObservableCollection<CarViewModel>();
        AddNewCarCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewCar);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> Cars { get; private set; }
    public ICommand AddNewCarCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Where `IPresentationService` is a service, which is intended to create and show a popup window. Instance of `IPresentationService` could be obtained via service location or dependency injection (`[Import]` means dependency injection using MEF).

Answer (score 0):

As the MainView has a button New Car,  the Main ViewModel might have a property NewCar.

You could create a new instance of a car when the button is clicked and pass the instance to the dialog that allows the user to enter values for the new car.

When the dialog is closed, the main view could do any additional validation (unique licence plate) against the collection of cars and when found correct, add the new car to the cars collection and possibly propagate this addition/change to the model.

This way the dialog is responsible for the details of the car and the main view is responsible for adding the car to the collection.